# Book involving time travel, hordes of Genghis Khan riding Harleys, and Legionaries with anti-tank weapons?

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, alternate-history

I'm trying to recall the title of a book involving time travel. It included warriors from different time periods being given modern technology. The Hordes of Genghis Khan were like a biker gang riding around on Harley Davidsons. Roman Legionaries were attacking with anti-tank weapons.

My question is: **Do you recall a book involving time travel, hordes of genhis khan riding harleys, and centurions with anti-tank weapons?**

Comment: Sounds like a Doctor Who plot.

Comment: How does the time travel come in? Do the Mongol hordes and the Roman legions travel to the future in time machines to obtain their bikes and bazookas? How did they get the time machines? Is there anything you remember about the story that you haven't told us? Were the Romans and the Mongols fighting each other, or were they all fighting against space aliens, or what? Were the Mongols shooting arrows from their bikes, or were they armed with blasters?

Comment: Interestingly enough, I had a friend run a Mage the Ascension game back in the early 90's where some Marauders were in fact mongols on harleys. And horses that made motorcycle noises.  I always assumed it was a product of his twisted mind, rather than from a book.  I'll be interested to know if he cribbed it from somewhere.

Comment: I remember a short story that sounds like that: a professor and his students traveling around a world where the timelines got all mangled in patches for a few months by unknown phenomena. Many patches of the world transformed into alternative realities. At the end, the phenomenon mostly cleared except for a few isolated issues and a bunch of people who disappeared after wandering into alternative patches when those returned to normal. **Update**: "Sidewise in Time" by Murray Leinster"

Comment: Instead of time travel, could it be the afterlife? Maybe something in the Heroes in Hell series?

Comment: I was also wondering about something by Leinster.

Comment: time's eye of arthur C Clarke has some time travel, I don't remember any roman but Alexander was there in it and Genghis Khan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't recall the Legions, but Mongols on Harley's were a part of Mozart in Mirrorshades, a short story by Bruce Sterling and Lewis Shiner. The background is that someone in the US invents a machine that opens portals to alternate timelines. The action took place in 18th century Vienna, where they found oil in the middle of the city, set up derricks on top of the palace, and ran a pipe back through the portal. The Viennese plot to kick them out and the mongols are called in to solve the problem. A sub-plot involved Mozart trying to get his Green Card so he could emigrate to the modern US.